# How to get key node from dynatree after init

Tags: dynatree

Hello I want get key from dynatree after create tree.
I use

```
$("#tree").dynatree("getTree").persistence.activeKey;
```

but it return null

Answer (score 0):

```
var rootNode = $("#tree").dynatree("getRoot");

alert(rootNode.data.key);

var children=rootNode .getChildren() ;
for(i=0;i<children.length;i++){
alert("child key:"+children[i].data.key);
}
```